# How to split column into multiple rows (with pipe as separator) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I've table1 like this:

`col_raw`

```
   |    COL1  |COL2|    COL3  |  COL4  |
   -------------------------------------
   |0123456789|Male|Basketball|Aquarius|
   -------------------------------------
```

I would like to convert table1 to table2 which is consist of this column header name

table2:

```
 Column Names: Phone Number | Gender | Hoby | Zodiak
```

Let me know if you ever query like this in mysql. Thank you!

Comment: Unless I have understood the question very wrong, can you check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, you always have 4 columns, you can use the below

```
select substring_index(column_name,'|',1) firstcol,
substring_index(substring_index(column_name,'|',2),'|',-1) secondcol,
substring_index(substring_index(column_name,'|',3),'|',-1) thirdcol,
substring_index(substring_index(column_name,'|',4),'|',-1) fourthcol
from table_name;
```

To understand the above, you can try running the below query, you will see how the substring_index is  being used multiple times in the above query to fetch the required details

```
select substring_index(column_name,'|',1),
substring_index(column_name,'|',2),
substring_index(column_name,'|',3),
substring_index(column_name,'|',4)
from table_name;
```